# jQuery .attr('data-order', sum); not work for parent div

Tags: jquery

I try to show data-order value inside a div with class "card" but works only in children div.
The value is the sum of checkbox value.

I try with :
 `$(".card").attr('data-order',  sum);`

`$(this).find(".card").attr('data-order',  sum);`

Using:

`$(this).find(".card").attr('data-order', "1");`
works fine but value is fixed...

`$(this).find(".risultato").attr('data-order' + sum );`  works fine but only for child elements inside div "card"

```js
// Trigger per filtri
$(".filter #sport").change(function(){
    var status = $(this).is(":checked") ? true : false;
    $(".sport").prop("checked",status);
});

$(".filter #relax").change(function(){
    var status = $(this).is(":checked") ? true : false;
    $(".relax").prop("checked",status);
});


$(".filter #family").change(function(){
    var status = $(this).is(":checked") ? true : false;
    $(".family").prop("checked",status);
});



// abilita calcoli
$(".filter input").change(function(){
  $("#risultatiquiz .card").each(function() {

 
    var sum = 0.00;
    $(this).find('.check-plus:checked').each(function() {
         sum += parseFloat($(this).val().trim()) || 0;
        // $(".card").addClass("" + sum);
           $(this).find(".card").addClass( "rosso" + sum);
           sum = sum;
         
    });

    $(this).find(".risultato").html('<span>Punteggio: </span>' + sum );
    $(this).find(".risultato").addClass( sum );
    $(this).find(".risultato").addClass( "rosso");
     $(this).find(".risultato").addClass( "blu");
 
    $(this).find(".risultato").append('<br> data-order=' + sum );
    
  //PROBLEM HERE
 $(".card").attr('data-order',  sum);
      
  });
     
  
  
}); 
 
  
// ORDINE 

var $sorted_items,
  getSorted = function(selector, attrName) {
      return $(
        $(selector).toArray().sort(function(a, b){
            var aVal = parseInt(a.getAttribute(attrName)),
                bVal = parseInt(b.getAttribute(attrName));
            return aVal - bVal;
        })
      );
  };

$sorted_items = getSorted('#risultatiquiz .card', 'data-order').clone();

$('#risultatiquiz').html( $sorted_items );
```

```css
.card {
  border: 0px solid #dadada;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.2s;
  width: 20%;
 margin:1%;
  float:left;
}

.card h3 {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 8px 0px;
/*   line-height: 20px !important;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important; */
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card .container {
  padding: 2px 14px;
}

.card p {
  margin: 14px 0;
display:inline-block;
}
.total_filter {background:#000; color:#fff; display:block;     display: inline-flex!important; border-radius:100px; }
.card input {display:block}
.card.rosso {background:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter">
  POINTS:
  <input type="checkbox" id="sport">
  <label> Sport</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="relax">
  <label> Relax</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="family">
  <label> Family</label>
</div>
<div id="risultatiquiz">
  <div class="card" data-order="0">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477414348463-c0eb7f1359b6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8Y2hhbmdlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="result"></h2>
      <h2 class="risultato"></h2>
      <input type="checkbox" value="5" class="check-plus sport"><label><strong>Sport<br></strong>5</label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="10" class="check-plus relax"><label><strong>Relax<br></strong>10</label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="9" class="check-plus family"><label><strong>Family<br></strong>9</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-order="0">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533073526757-2c8ca1df9f1c?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8Y2hhbmdlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="result"></h2>
      <h2 class="risultato"></h2>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="check-plus sport"><label><strong>Sport<br></strong>1 €</label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="3" class="check-plus relax"><label><strong>Relax<br></strong>3</label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="4" class="check-plus family"><label><strong>Family<br></strong>4</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bu1zghd8/10/

Thanks

Comment: Please post a [mcve] here, not just a link to jsfiddle.

Comment: Are you trying to add a new `sum` to an existing element via `.data()` or are you trying to show that `sum` inside a specific DIV element?

Comment: `this` in the loop is the `.card` element, so `$(this).find(".card")` doesn't find anything.

Comment: Use `$(this).attr("data-order")`

Comment: @Twisty There's no use of `.data()` in the code. He's using it in  a `.sort()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Solved using :

```
$(this).attr('data-order',  sum);
```

Thanks to Barmar

Comment: Glad you got your answer. Here is an updated fiddle in case you want some hints on how to improve your code: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6wd9gket/12/